# extra data is being entered into Arraylist

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jsp, servlets

I have created an arraylist, that takes the information of the user i.e., name,age and city.
When i'm entering the data from the register form like

**input is :**

[image: input]

**output is:**

[image: output]

**Whereas the Expected Output is:**

```
name : a
age : 1
city  : b
```

**I'm getting the wrong output as shown in the above figure. Can you please help me out with this issue.** ***Below is my code:***

my register.jsp page is

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="/tutorial/register">
<table>
<tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>
<input type="text" name="name">
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>age</td>
<td>
<input type="number" name="age">
</td>
</tr>
<tr><td>city</td>
<td><input type="text" name="city"></td>
</tr>
<tr><td></td>
<td>
<input type="submit" name="name" >
 </td>
 </tr>
</table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Describe you problem clearly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because for both the fields you have the "name" as name.

```
<input type="text" name="name">
<input type="submit" name="name" >
```

So change submit button name to something else like below.

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" >
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the same "name" tag for both the first input text and the submit button, and that's why both input values are combined in the sent data.

If you change the submit one, data will be submitted as you expected.